# Google Drive REST API: Getting sporadic 500 errors as of Feb 25

Tags: google-drive-api

We have an app that heavily relies on Google Push Notifications to watch for changes on a user's Drive.  Starting in the evening of the 25th, we started seeing significantly increased latency in our API requests as well as sporadic 500 errors.  The vast majority of our requests are to these two endpoints:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes
```

We weren't experiencing any of these problems before the 25th.

Comment: I think this an error in Google server and as of now, I cannot find any related issues about it. I suggest that when an unexpected error occurred while processing the request, implement exponential backoff as stated in this [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error).